# Generic cache method - when T is an int, how can I differentiate between null and zero?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I am trying to implement a caching solution.

When caching an `int` value I want to distinguish between 0 and the non-existance of a cache (`null`). Therefore I have used `var cachedData = (int?)_cacheImplementation.GetItem(cacheKey)`.

When caching a `T` value I don't think that I can use this approach because I can't add the nullable operator onto `T`.

The result is that I have to use a separate method for `int` cache retrieval and `T` cache retreival (as below), but I would like to unify them into a single method if possible.

Ideally I would like just the `T` version and to be able to use `int` as the type for `T`. But differentiating `0` from `null` is tripping me up.

```
public IApplicationCachingServiceResult<int> GetCache(
    string cacheKey
    , Func<int> valueFactory
    )
{
    var cachedData = (int?)_cacheImplementation.GetItem(cacheKey);
    return cachedData.HasValue
        ? new ApplicationCachingServiceResult<int>(cachedData.Value)
        : new ApplicationCachingServiceResult<int>(
            CreateCacheItem(cacheKey, valueFactory)
            );
}

public IApplicationCachingServiceResult<T> GetCache<T>(
    string cacheKey
    , Func<T> valueFactory
    )
{
    return _cacheImplementation.GetItem(cacheKey) is T cachedData
        ? new ApplicationCachingServiceResult<T>(cachedData)
        : new ApplicationCachingServiceResult<T>(
            CreateCacheItem(cacheKey, valueFactory)
            );
}
```

_cacheImplementation.GetItem is implemented as follows:

```
public object GetItem(string cacheKey)
{
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out var cachedValue))
    {
        return cachedValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: as you already figured out you need another implementation for `int`, as that type does not have a `null`-value. So you need two functions, one for `T: struct` and one for `T: class`. The `Nullable<T>`-type than applies to the latter.

Comment: How is _cacheImplementation declared/implemented? If its values are of type "object", and it accept struct values, then the "T" syntax should be fine even for "int" values.

Comment: In your generic `GetCache`, `is T` will evaluate to `false` for `null` when `T` is `int`. What is the problem?